# Como deserializo un string para obtener mi objeto c#

Tags: c#

Tengo lo siguiente en c#, lo recibo de una respuesta (*response.Error.Content*):

```
"{ message: "Ocurrio un error", code: "401"}"
```

Lo que intento es obtener el **"message"** en una variable, pero al intentar deserializar me agrega una llave más:

```
dynamic stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Error.Content);
```

En este momento *stuff* es igual a; como puedes ver tiene un par de llaves

```
{{ message: "Ocurrio un error", code: "401"}}
```

como puedo obtener message del objeto para hacer algo como esto:

```
var errMsg = stuff.message;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crear una classe para ayudarlo a interpretarlo con los campos del js como parametros por ejemplo:

```
  class Stuff
    {
        
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
    }
```

Usar esta línea para deserializar:

```
        string json = @"{ message:""Ocurrio un error"", code: ""401"" }";//Respuesta 
        Stuff stuff =   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stuff>(json);
```